# Find range between two words and iterate through it with loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a method for defining range between two words and iterate through it to copy paste values from one worksheet to another. There is some strange reason it does not work.

1. I specify row, it is 18, my code starts from row 20? So it copies everything starting from row 20. O_o
2. It does not detect range correctly as it copies values below my words as well? I have checked that I don't have same words elsewhere.

Any suggestions?

Here is code for calling method:

```
Sub dsfdsfdsfds()
    copyOptionsToTable 18, CalculationItemOM1
End Sub
```

Here is method:

```
Private Sub copyOptionsToTable(RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    'Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
    Dim OptionsRange As Range
    Dim cell, x
            
    'Set FirstWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("W:W").Find("OPTIOONS START", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'Set SecondWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("W:W").Find("OPTIOONS END", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set OptionsRange = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find("[OPTIOONS START]"), OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find("[OPTIOONS END]"))
    
    x = 0
    
    ' Copy - Paste process
    For Each cell In OptionsRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Or cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).Offset(0 + x, 0).Value = cell.Offset(0 + x, -20).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).Offset(0 + x, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0 + x, 2).Value
        End If
        
        x = x + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Source sheet:

[image]

Output sheet:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Output still looks like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already incrementing `cell` by one row inside the loop - you don't need to further offset that using `x`

```vb
Set OptionsRange = OperatingWorksheet.Range( _
        OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find("[OPTIOONS START]").Offset(1,0), _ 
        OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find("[OPTIOONS END]").Offset(-1, 0))
    
x = 0

' Copy - Paste process
For Each cell In OptionsRange.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Or cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste)
            .Offset(x, 0).Value = cell.Offset(0, -20).Value
            .Offset(x, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End With
        x = x + 1 '<< only increment if you copied values...
    End If
Next cell
```

Also I'm not sure this line does what you intend?

```
If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Or cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
```

maybe

```
If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It is closer to target but output still looks strange. I don't get it why it does not start from row 18 and there are empty spaces between. Cells on source Worksheet are empty. I have added new screenshot.

Comment: If you don't want spaces then move the x = x+1 inside the `If`  Sorry I should have caught that - edited above.

Comment: Oh maybe I should finish for today with coding... :) One issue left, now it starts from row 19, instead of 18. I am thinking is there are something my line for defining range?

Comment: Does it count first or last cell as well, then loop thinks that it is within the range? I need to iterate between `[OPTIOONS START]` and `[OPTIOONS END]` without taking in consideration any of these.

Comment: I don't see anything which would account for that - maybe put a break on one of the lines inside the With block and see what's going on the first time it gets hit - what is the value of `x` and what is the value of `cell` ?

Comment: Thank you master! Now I will have a nice sleep, otherwise I wouldn't